# Switch profile in Konsole from command line?

Tags: command-line, konsole

I know that its possible to set profile for new tab, but what if i need to switch profile for current tab?

Answer (score 11):

From [Changing Konsole colors in KDE using the shell](http://abdussamad.com/archives/503-Changing-Konsole-colors-in-KDE.html) the solution is quite simple but cover color

```bash
konsoleprofile colors=WhiteOnBlack
# or
konsoleprofile colors=GreenOnBlack
```

Where the value come from menu `Settings` > `Edit Current Profile…` > select `Appearance tab`.

#### Tmux

You need to wrap the command in the *passthrough escape sequence* inside `tmux` session, otherwise it won't do anything:

```
printf '\033Ptmux;\033\033]50;konsoleprofile colors=GreenOnBlack\007\033\\'
```

Here is are tiny helpers I put in my `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
# Konsole color changing
theme-night() {
  switch-term-color "colors=TomorrowNightBlue"
}
theme-light() {
  switch-term-color "colors=Tomorrow"
}
switch-term-color() {
  arg="${1:-colors=Tomorrow}"
  if [[ -z "$TMUX" ]]
  then
    konsoleprofile "$arg"
  else
    printf '\033Ptmux;\033\033]50;%s\007\033\\' "$arg"
  fi
}
```

### Credits

- Thanks to `nicm` on `#tmux` channel.
- my gist on Github: https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/9973056

Comment: `konsoleprofile` command modifies the current profile. It doesn't switch it